# Default implementation for interface ? or leave as null

Tags: java, interface, implementation

So the question is not really easy to understand but I will try my best, lets say I have an interface :

```
interface OnWindowMoveListener{
    void onWindowMove(MotionEvent motionEvent);
}
```

Now in my class I have

```
OnWindowMoveListener onWindowMoveListener;

public void setOnWindowMoveListener(OnWindowMoveListener onWindowMoveListener){
    this.onWindowMoveListener = onWindowMoveListener;
}
```

Later in my code the `onWindowMoveListener.onWindowMove()` is called but I dont want to have to check if the onWindowMoveListener has been set by the user and thus not null, how would I create a default implementation for this listener ? Would I have to manually implement the interfaces in the main method of my class in case the user doesnt implement them himself or is there another way of doing this ? I have always been checking if the interface has been implemented before calling but want to know if there is a cleaner way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: It is normal and common to simply check if the listener object set by the user is non-null.

Comment: the containing class can implement your listener.. `public class MyClass implements OnWindowMoveListener`.. and then assign it `this.onWindowMoveListener = this`. now the value won't start as `null`, but that doesn't mean the user won't try to set a `null` listener - you still need to check for `null`.

Comment: @VGR the code doesnt start to look neat if I have to check for each listener to see if its non null before calling it thats why I am looking for an alternative solution :/

Comment: @trooper the user setting a null listener wont be a big problem but what will happen when I call the `onWindowMoveListener` in this case ?

Comment: @Amroelaswar well as part of implementing `OnMoveWindowListener` on your containing class, it now has a `onWindowMove` method of its own. - it will be executed - leave it empty for no action.

Comment: also, I would move the code that triggers the listeners into their own methods - call it `triggerWindowMoveListener` - put your null check in there. It won't look nearly as messy if every listener is triggered in the same way (from code that is quite frankly boilerplate).

Comment: @trooper Oh I see what you mean, I forgot that I would have to implement the methods, for the moment I have a method that sets empty default listeners for all the listeners but I am looking for new cleaner ways to do this so thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Doing nullcheck is not a cost operation, but if you really need to avoid it, your best option would be to use the Null Object Design Pattern.

Create a implementation of your interface which does nothing, and than use it as default value of the onWindownMoveListener.

For more information about this design pattern, consult: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object/java-0